# Find the most repeated word group with PHP

Tags: php

In a text, is it possible to find the most repeated word group with PHP ?

For example, my text is "lkjlk Star Wars jkjhyyyg h Star Wars jkhk Star Wars"
and the result will be Star Wars.

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: In case you are wondering, the downvotes are likely because we like to see posters make an attempt at the question, which would show you know Stack Overflow isn't a free code-writing service. How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "lkjlk Star Wars jkjhyyyg h Star Wars jkhk Star Wars";

$words = array_count_values(explode(' ', $string));

arsort($words);

var_dump($words);
```

that code produces the following array.

```
array (size=6)
  'Star' => int 3
  'Wars' => int 3
  'jkhk' => int 1
  'h' => int 1
  'jkjhyyyg' => int 1
  'lkjlk' => int 1
```

Comment: Thanks  But your solution returns one word. Star or wars. Is it possible to return the word group Star Wars? Sorry for my english